# tracking a library as we import it

Tags: python

In python when I import a library for example "from hippylib import *" , I want to be able to trace back the location of the library (I have multiple copies). I would really appreciate the help thank you.

Comment: `import hippylib; print(hippylib.__file__)`?

Comment: Alternatively, if you know a class or a function that was defined into `hippylib`, then you could use `print(inspect.getmodule(class_or_function).__file__)`.

Comment: use any tool to identify the location of the path, by clicking on package name or function name (ctrl + mouseRightClick). or use commands to identify the location of the path. **__file__**

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you're looking for:

```
import zipfile

print(zipfile.__file__)
```

Results in something like:

```
c:\dev\bin\python37-64\Lib\zipfile.py
```